# NOAUTH Authentication required. [tcp://redis:6379]. How to fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' in my docker container for redis?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

Some time the server is working, but after a certain number of requests I get php errors for all connection with redis

```
    Predis\Connection\ConnectionException: `SELECT` failed: NOAUTH Authentication required. [tcp://redis:6379]
    #66 vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(155): onConnectionError
    #65 vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(263): connect
    #64 vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(180): getResource
    #63 vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(288): write
    #62 vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(394): writeRequest
    #61 vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(110): executeCommand
    #60 vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php(331): executeCommand
    #59 vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php(314): __call
```

redis run on my server in docker container
Docker

```
a45f25ed7ebb        laradock_redis        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago          Up 30 minutes       0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                     laradock_redis_1
```

docker-compose logs redis

```
redis_1       | 1:C 08 Jan 08:56:23.036 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis_1       | 1:C 08 Jan 08:56:23.036 # Redis version=4.0.8, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis_1       | 1:C 08 Jan 08:56:23.036 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis_1       | 1:M 08 Jan 08:56:23.038 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_1       | 1:M 08 Jan 08:56:23.038 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
redis_1       | 1:M 08 Jan 08:56:23.038 # Server initialized
redis_1       | 1:M 08 Jan 08:56:23.038 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis_1       | 1:M 08 Jan 08:56:23.038 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
    redis:
      build: ./redis
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_SAVE_PATH}/redis:/data
      ports:
        - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
      networks:
        - backend
```

Dockerfile for redis

```
FROM redis:latest

LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"

RUN echo 'sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=65535' >> /etc/rc.local
RUN echo 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf

VOLUME /data

EXPOSE 6379

CMD ["redis-server"]
```

Tell me how to configure redis to work stably.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a nefarious person or bot is getting to your Redis server and configures it to require a password at the least, but possibly trying to use it for mining crypto currency. Protect your network and set a password for Redis yourself (the `requirepass` configuration directive) to protect against further attacks.

Comment: You can just run the standard `redis` image; the image you build on top of it has no substantial differences.  (Neither file in `/etc` you touch is used and the other lines duplicate the standard image's settings.)  You need to make sysctl changes from a root shell on the host; since the kernel is shared across all containers and host processes, changes in how the kernel memory allocator works are host-global.